# React, states don't match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to check if two password fields match and then update a state to true or false based on this. I am using Refs for the input fields and running `matchPw` on input change.

However the state does not update first time and go out of sync. This is what I have tried:

```
const matchPw = () => {
    let enteredValue = pwOne.current.value;
    let enteredRepeatedValue = pwTwo.current.value;

      if (enteredValue === enteredRepeatedValue) {
        setError((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          pwMatch: true,
        }));
        console.log("match: " + pwError.pwResetMatchWarning);
      } else {
        setError((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          pwMatchW: false,
        }));
        console.log("do not match: " + pwError.pwResetMatchWarning);
      }
}
```

Comment: The only state being interacted with here is `setError`, which is never observed afterward.  What specific state update are you observing to not work as expected, and how are you observing it?

Comment: Please show the whole file or where `matchPw` is used